# How to get the plain user credentials while login with spring security before encrypting them?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I'm working on a webapplication with highlevel privacy. I wanne store the username and the encrypted password of each user in a db table and i wanne store a AnonymousUserName in an other table to associate personal details with. The AnonymousUserName should be created by hashing the real username and salting the hash with the plain password. so the administrator has no possibility to find out the AnonymousUserName because the password is just stored encrypted in the db.

Nevertheless i have to know which AnonymousUserName belongs to the logged in user. So I want to hash the username and salt the hash with the plain password each time the user loggs in and save the generated AnonymousUserName as SessionAtribute that is deleted again when the user leaves the app.

My Authentication-Manager configuration looks very simple at the moment.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:repository="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/repository/spring-repository-1.5.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">


    <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
        <intercept-url pattern="/login"
            access="permitAll"/>
        <access-denied-handler />
        <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"/>
        <logout />
    </http>
    <beans:bean id="encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.bcrypt.BCryptPasswordEncoder"/>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="jdbcUserService">
            <password-encoder ref="encoder"/>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>

    <beans:bean id="jdbcUserService"
        class="de.tuberlin.livefeedback.dao.SpringSecurityDaoImpl">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <beans:property name="enableGroups" value="true" />
        <beans:property name="enableAuthorities" value="false" />
        <beans:property name="groupAuthoritiesByUsernameQuery">
            <beans:value>SELECT R.idROLE, R.NAME, P.NAME
            FROM ROLE R 
            JOIN USER_ROLE RM on R.idROLE = RM.user_role_role
            JOIN USER U on U.idUSER = RM.user_role_user
            JOIN ROLE_PERMISSION RP ON RP.role_permission_role = R.idROLE
            JOIN PERMISSION P ON P.idPERMISSION = RP.role_permission_permission
            WHERE U.login=?

            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="usersByUsernameQuery">
            <beans:value>select login,password,enabled from USER where login = ?
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
        <beans:property name="authoritiesByUsernameQuery">
            <beans:value>SELECT U.login, P.name FROM USER U, PERMISSION P WHERE U.login = ? AND P.idPERMISSION IN
                (SELECT role_permission_permission FROM ROLE_PERMISSION WHERE role_permission_role IN
                (SELECT user_role_role FROM USER_ROLE WHERE user_role_user=
                (SELECT idUSER FROM USER WHERE login = ? LIMIT 1)))
            </beans:value>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>
</beans:beans>
```

My idea was to override the method that handles the httpRequest when the user loggs in with his credentials like the following pseudocode should illustrate:

```
@Override
void authenticate (String username, String password){
     String anonymousUserName = hash(username, password);
     httpSession.setAttribute("anonymousUserName", anonymousUserName);
     super(username, password) //to do the authentication-stuff
}
```

Because I have no idea if there is any method that i could override this way and where it could be found, i'm writing this question.

So, is there any possibility to do what I want in a similar way?

thanking you in anticipation

Comment: No; you want to _hash_ the password.

Comment: I really want to hash the username to ensure that the db administrator can not find out which user has done what.

Comment: Can you please post your full Spring Security config?

Comment: done. please apologize my ugly sql statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use an `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` and implement your logic in its `onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication)` method, where you can get all the necessary information/objects.

In practice, this would mean to subclass the `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` which is used by the default configuration, and the implemented behavior of which you most probably would want to keep. In the configuration you can then wire up that class with the `<form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="...">` attribute.

Comment: what do I have to do in my spring-security-config to let the methode be invoked?

Comment: +1: Instead of writing a subclass of `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler` I recommend to write a MultiAuthenticationSuccessHandler (implements `AuthenticationSuccesHandler`) that is able to invoke several AuthenticationSuccesHandlers

Comment: Thanks @Ralph, using composition would be indeed much cleaner than inheritance.

Comment: If I do so and write my 
AuthenticationSuccessHandlerImpl implements AuthenticationSuccessHandler.
Must I invoke the standard AuthenticationSuccessHandler too? And how?

Comment: You'll have to invoke one of the standard implementations if you want to keep the redirection logic (`SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler`: redirects to a default url, `SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler`: redirects back to the protected url the user tried to access without being authenticated first.) You can achieve this by subclassing one of them, or better to simply instantiate one as a normal bean (these are just POJOs), and invoke both your own implementation and the standard one in turn (as Ralph suggested).

Answer (score 1):

I have something similar like your requirement in my application, and I did something like this to achieve the desired behavior:

```
 <bean id="authenticationSuccessHandler" class="com.company.AuthenticationSuccessHandler" />

<http use-expressions="true" auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll"/>
    <access-denied-handler />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/" authentication-sucess-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"/>
    <logout />
</http>
```

The `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` class implements `org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AuthenticationSuccessHandler`, and on method onAuthenticationSuccess you'll have access to your request, and session:

```
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
        Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (authentication.isAuthenticated()) {
       // add to session
    }
}
```